# mySQL - Searching a row by its row number?

Tags: mysql, indexing, row

Question from a total mySQL newbie.  I'm trying to build a table containing information about machine parts (screws, brackets, cylinders, etc), and each part corresponds to a machine that the part belongs to.  The database will be designed so that whenever the client reads from the table, all of the parts from one specified machine will be selected.  I'm trying to figure out the fastest way in which all rows falling under a certain category can be read from the disk.

Sorting the table is not an option as many people might be adding rows to the table at once.  Using a table for each machine is not practical either, since new machines might be created.  I expect it to have to handle lots of INSERT and SELECT operations, but almost no DELETE operations.  I've come up with a plan to quickly identify each part belonging to any machine, and I've come to ask if it's practical:

Each row containing the data for a machine part will contain the row number of the previous part and the next part for the same machine.  A separate table will contain the row number of the last part of each machine that appears on the table.  A script could follow the list of these 'pointers,' skipping to different parts of the table until all of the parts were found.

TL;DR

Would this approach of searching a row by its row number be any faster than searching instead by an integer primary key (since a primary key does not necessarily indicate a position on the table)?  How much faster would it be?  Would it yield noticeable performance improvements over using an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a terrible approach. [Selecting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) rows which match some criteria is a fundamental feature of MySQL (or any other DB engine really...).

Just create a column called `machine_id` in your parts table and give an id to each machine.
You could put your machines in a `machines` table and use their primary key in the `machine_id` field of the `parts` table.

Then all you have to do to retrieve ALL parts of machine 42 is:
`SELECT * FROM parts WHERE machine_id = 42;`

If your database is massive you may also consider [indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) the `machine_id` column for better performances.